# How to recreate fragment without adding its previous state

Tags: android, fragment

i want to recreate or refreash a fragment without adding previuos state.I searched many thing but not find any appropriate method.please give me some suggestion.......

Comment: Which code you have to create a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is [FragmentTransaction.replace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29).

E.g.:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

However, remember that you can only add a single instance of a Fragment class once. Trying to add the same instance again will result in a `Fragment already added` exception. To resolve this, either get a new instance of the Fragment class you need to add using [MyFragmentClass.instantiate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#instantiate%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29) or `new MyFragmentClass()`.

Comment: That is not possible, unless you use some sort of data restoration in the Fragment's constructor or `onCreate/onResume()`. Essentially, the `new MyFragmentClass()` will always return a new instance of the class. You should include some code in your answer, so we can better understand your issue.